# how to install pecl_http ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, pecl

I'm trying to install `pecl_http`
i have installed

> sudo apt-get install php-pear
>       sudo apt-get install php5-dev
>       sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev
>       sudo apt-get install
>       libcurl4-openssl-dev

But when i try this

> sudo apt-get install pecl_http

I got this

```
downloading pecl_http-2.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-2.2.0.tgz (172,406 bytes)
.....................................done: 172,406 bytes
65 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
where to find zlib [/usr] : 
where to find libcurl [/usr] : 
where to find libevent [/usr] : 
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root2eJFqQ/pecl_http-2.2.0
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable extended HTTP support... yes, shared
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for mbstate_t... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking wctype.h usability... yes
checking wctype.h presence... yes
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getdomainname... yes
checking for mbrtowc... yes
checking for mbtowc... yes
checking for iswalnum... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for idna.h... found in /usr
checking for zlib.h... found in /usr
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.3.4
checking for curl/curl.h... found in /usr
checking for curl-config... found: /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for curl version >= 7.18.2... 7.22.0
checking for SSL support in libcurl... yes
checking for openssl support in libcurl... no
checking for gnutls support in libcurl... no
checking for ares support in libcurl... no
checking for bundled SSL CA info... /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
checking for event2/event.h... not found
configure: WARNING: continuing without libevent support
checking for ext/raphf support... no
configure: error: Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr' failed
```

anyone can help me? I need to solve this in a hurry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the missing package `pecl/raphf` and then simply add it to your php.ini file

```
$ sudo pecl install raphf
```

and add `extension=raphf.so` to your a config file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php5/conf.d/raphf.ini
```

Now try to install pecl_http again.

```
$ sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

Comment: parsePackageName(): invalid package name "raphf.so" in "raphf.so"
invalid package name/package file "raphf.so"
install failed

Comment: i had raphf.so and propro.so in /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs and i have configure it in <b>php.ini</b><br/> extension = raphf.so <br/> extension = propro.so

Comment: try without the `.so` part

Comment: `pecl/raphf is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.0.4
install failed` it was installed, but when try to install `sudo pecl install pecl_http`, i got that message above `Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini`

Comment: add `extension=raphf.so` to your php.ini file then. You will have to add it to the correct php.ini file though. `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is the default install path for cli and `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` if you are using apache2